# Seaborn, how to gradient color distplot depending on the x-axis value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'd like to gradient-color the plot line in the Seaborn's `distplot`, depending on the x-axis value. For example if the value is 1, then the colour is blue, when 1.1 then it's blue and goes toward green, and so on, and so on. For example like on the plot-draft below:

[image]

The problem is, that I don't how to set colour map manually in Seaborn or how to force x-dependend coloring of the plot's curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) has been deprecated. In the current seaborn version, [`kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) draws a kde curve.

You can grab the generated line with `ax.get_lines()`. And then create a multicolored line similar to [this tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html).

Here is some code to demonstrate the idea (currently it would also still work with `distplot`):

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)
data = np.random.uniform(-1, 1.1, (5, 1000)).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()
ax = sns.kdeplot(x=data)
x, y = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()
segments = np.array([x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:], y[1:]]).T.reshape(-1, 2, 2)
norm = plt.Normalize(x.min(), x.max())
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='turbo_r', norm=norm)
lc.set_array(x[:-1])
lc.set_linewidth(2)
ax.get_lines()[0].remove()
line = ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.fill_between(x, y, color='purple', alpha=0.1, hatch='xx')
ax.margins(x=0)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: kdeplot with colored line]

Comment: Thanks for your answer JohanC, beautiful curve.
Two questions:

1. Why we transpose and reshape data here ? `segments = np.array([x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:], y[1:]]).T.reshape(-1, 2, 2)`

2. Can I use `get_lines()` x, in another plot with the same x range, if I want to have the same color range with respect to x values ?

Comment: 1. The transpose and reshape puts the data in the format needed for `LineCollection`. Each short line in the `LineCollection` is of the form `[[x0, y0], [x1,y1]]` and the an other dimension is added to have multiple short lines. 2. Yes, you'd need to reuse the `norm` and then`lc.set_array(x[:-1])` for that other collection.